# jstree shortcut and shortcut_label for custom contextmenu not working

Tags: javascript, plugins, contextmenu, jstree, shortcut

Options "shortcut" and "shortcut_label" does not seem to work when I use them in a contextmenu item. The context menu displays as expected, but the shortcut (keyCode for F10) does not work and the shortcut_label does not display.

### My code (only the relevant part under "contextmenu" plugin options) is as below:

```
"MyMenuItem": {
    "separator_before": false,
    "separator_after": false,
    "label": "MyMenuItem",
    "_disabled": function (obj) {
        switch ($node.type) {
            case "question":
                return false;
                break;
            case "answer":
                return true;
                break;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    },
    "action": function (obj) {
        loadActionScreen($node);
    },
    "shortcut": 121,
    "shortcut_label": "F10"
}
```

---

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

### **Edited on 02/08/2018:**

From the plugin documentation: "keyCode which will trigger the action *if the menu is open* (for example 113 for rename, which equals F2)". 
That clears the air on the key action. However, I am still not able to get the shortcut_label to display.
Thanks!

Comment: Try using chrome inspect element and watch the console for errors. My `F2` works, however, the css for the `shortcut_label` in the html is such that "F2" is not visible.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris K. I do not get any error in the console. Tried with 112 for F2 key. Nothing happens. Have been looking around for online documentation, but to no avail.